# Probability on a given sample mean given standard deviation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The standard deviation for a given jobs' wage is $ \sigma = 4200 $.

What is the probability that the mean $ \overline{X}_{40}$ of a random sample $ X_1,X_2,X_3 \dots X_{40}$ is greater than the population's mean.

I haven't encountered a similar question to this one , so I have no attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per $n=40$ is greater enough, you can use CLT to say that

$$\overline{X}_{40}\dot{\sim}N\Bigg(\mu;\frac{4200^2}{40}\Bigg)$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[\overline{X}_{40}>\mu]=\frac{1}{2}$$

EDIT: answering to  your comment,

$$\mathbb{P}[\overline{X}_{40}>\mu+50]=\mathbb{P}[Z>\frac{50}{4200}\sqrt{40}]=1-\Phi(0.075)\approx 0.47$$

Comment: What about the probability that $\overline{X}_{40}$ is greater by 50 than $\mu$ ?
Is it $ P[\overline{X}_{40} > \mu + 50]  = 0.5367359 $?

Comment: @Mahajna : added an edit...it is the complement to one of your result...about 0.47